# RoR Puma: Start request repeated too quickly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, puma, rbenv

I'm having a very complicated problem on my production server on aws ec2.

When I try to start the puma service, it is returning an error, and journalctl -e displays this to me:

```
ubuntu : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/ubuntu ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl daemon-reload
pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by ubuntu(uid=0)
Reloading.
pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Received disconnect from my-ip port 63644:11:  [preauth]
Disconnected from authenticating user root my-ip port 63644 [preauth]
  ubuntu : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/ubuntu ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start puma-website.service
pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by ubuntu(uid=0)
Started Puma HTTP Server.
pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 4.3.5 (ruby 2.7.1-p83), codename: Mysterious Traveller
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: production
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
/home/ubuntu/apps/my-project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/puma-4.3.5/lib/puma/launcher.rb:216:in `initialize
        from /home/ubuntu/apps/my-project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/puma-4.3.5/lib/puma/launcher.rb:216:i
        from /home/ubuntu/apps/my-project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/puma-4.3.5/lib/puma/launcher.rb:216:i
        from /home/ubuntu/apps/my-project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/puma-4.3.5/lib/puma/launcher.rb:105:i
        from /home/ubuntu/apps/my-project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/puma-4.3.5/lib/puma/single.rb:103:in 
        from /home/ubuntu/apps/my-project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/puma-4.3.5/lib/puma/launcher.rb:172:i
        from /home/ubuntu/apps/my-project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/puma-4.3.5/lib/puma/cli.rb:80:in `run
        from /home/ubuntu/apps/my-project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/puma-4.3.5/bin/puma:10:in `<top (requ
        from /home/ubuntu/apps/my-project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/puma:23:in `load'
        from /home/ubuntu/apps/my-project/shared/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/bin/puma:23:in `<main>'
puma-website.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
puma-website.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
puma-website.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
puma-website.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Stopped Puma HTTP Server.
Started Puma HTTP Server.
```

My puma.rb in the project:

```
max_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
min_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MIN_THREADS") { max_threads_count }
threads min_threads_count, max_threads_count

port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }
environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }
pidfile ENV.fetch("PIDFILE") { "tmp/pids/server.pid" }

plugin :tmp_restart
```

My deploy.rb:

```
set :rbenv_ruby_string, '2.7.1'

set :application, "my-project"
set :repo_url, "git@my-repo"

shared_path = "/home/ubuntu/apps/my-project/shared"
release_path = "/home/ubuntu/apps/my-project"

set :user,            'ubuntu'
set :puma_threads,    [4, 16]
set :puma_workers,    0

set :linked_files, %w{config/master.key}


namespace :puma do
  desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
  task :make_dirs do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
    end
  end

  before 'deploy:starting', 'puma:make_dirs'
end

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision do
    on roles(:app) do

      # Update this to your branch name: master, main, etc. Here it's main
      unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
        puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
        puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
        exit
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Initial Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end

  desc 'Restart application'
    task :restart do
      on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
        invoke 'puma:restart'
      end
  end

  before :starting,     :check_revision
  after  :finishing,    :cleanup
end

set :pty,             true
set :use_sudo,        false
set :stage,           :production
set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache
set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :ssh_options,     { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) }
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true
```

And my puma service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Puma HTTP Server
After=network.target


[Service]
# Foreground process (do not use --daemon in ExecStart or config.rb)
Type=simple
# Preferably configure a non-privileged user
User=ubuntu
Group=ubuntu
# Specify the path to your puma application root
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/apps/my_project/current
# Helpful for debugging socket activation, etc.
Environment=RAILS_ENV=production


# The command to start Puma
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/shims/bundle exec puma -C /home/ubuntu/apps/my_project/current/config/puma.rb

Restart=always


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My Nginx is running correctly. However only my puma service does not go up.

And in the path ".rbenv/shims/ I don't see the puma, and I don't know why:
[image]

Please, if anyone knows how to help me, I am very grateful, since this problem is occurring in my production.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

ok, solved it; thing is to have same puma version installed above and in your Gemfile (this prevent error right after puma.service start and hangs). So, whatch your /var/syslog for errors. kr.

Comment: interesting, only answer, which works for sure btw. got -1 ...